# How to mention that I'm good at utilizing both old/classical method of learning along with new ones (e.g. MOOC) on my résumé?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

In the last 2 years I've completed quite a few books as well as online certification courses relevant to my field of expertise, and those have helped me a lot in expanding my breath and depth of knowledge. I am trying to mention this as a bullet point in the summary section of my résumé. As of now, I've come up with the following:

> - A voracious learner, embracing and thriving on resources old (books,
>   research papers) and new (MOOC, NanoDegrees) alike.

Although it sounds okay to me, I think the wording can be a bit more professional. I'd like to take the examples out of the parentheses, but not able to think how. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ah thanks, didn't cross my mind. Would you mind posting it as an answer? I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of reorganizing the sentence so that what's in parentheses doesn't disrupt the flow is to move it all to the end.

Like this:

- A voracious learner, embracing and thriving on resources old and new alike, such as books, research papers, MOOC, and NanoDegrees.